# Security Error in Dart VM

Tags: dart, dartium, dart-html

I need add iframe with YouTube embed source via Dart but it throws an exception:

```dart
void main() {

  String videoID = "1nXRkk7Szu4";

  IFrameElement frame = new IFrameElement();
  frame.width = "560";
  frame.height = "315";
  frame.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/$videoID";
  frame.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "true");
  frame.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");

  querySelector("#sample_container_id").children.add(frame);

}
```

> Breaking on exception: SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

It is OK via JavaScript.

**Script was updated.**

**UPDATE:** I found the way. I added sandbox attribute with these values: "allow-same-origin allow-scripts" + I turned on HTML5 with suffix "?rel=0&html5=1" in the src.

Comment: I just tried this with a bunch of video IDs and could not reproduce the problem. Can you post the value of $videoID?

Comment: I updated script. I forgot add final part of script which is adding to element as a child + there is some $videoID now.

Comment: Hmmm. I still cannot reproduce the problem. Are you running this in Dart Editor? If so, what version of the editor are you using?

Comment: Editor version is 1.0.0_r30798 and SDK version is 1.0.0.10_r30798.

Comment: Same Editor and SDK version as me, but I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe Dartium does problems. My version is 31.0.1650.39 (1593).

Comment: I found out when I turn off debugger, the problem disappears.

Comment: Problem is not in SDK. I tried add iframe into html file without script and the same problem appeared.

Comment: Can you please file a bug? http://www.dartbug.com. And perhaps add exactly how you are using the debugger?

Comment: Ok, I created new issue. https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15822